# "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error when I try to parse HTML page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to parse price list which is in "span" tags with "class". Numbers has a specific setting (2 400 p) so I also need to remove spaces and "p" letter.
This is my code below:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("1.html"))
for link in soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "b-sbutton mod_price skin_product size_normal scheme_available" }):
links = link.get_text()
print(links)
links_len = len(links)
int(links_len)
for links_len in links:
    a = links[links_len]
    a.replace(' ', '')
    a.replace('р', '')
print(links)
```

But when I try to run the script there is an error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_data.py", line 9, in <module>
    a = links[links_len]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're looping over a string with each `links_len`being one char of the string, and then you're using that char to access an index of `links`. Its telling you to use an integer to specify an index, not a char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up lists, strings, indexes. You can make it using a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("1.html"))
links = [link.text.replace(' ', '').replace('p', '') 
         for link in soup.find_all("span", 
                                   {"class": "b-sbutton mod_price skin_product size_normal scheme_available"})]
```

Comment: `.replace(' p', '')` this is not the same as replacing `' '` and `p` individually, is it?

Comment: @TimCastelijns oops, correct, thanks. Didn't notice the space as a separator.

Comment: But there is also space between 2 and 400